# angular ajax: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax

I'm trying to sent `html` as `json` in `http post request`. But when I'm trying to make `$http.post` request, I've got the following error:

```
angular.js:12783 SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
    at fromJson (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1274:14)
    at defaultHttpResponseTransform (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9703:16)
    at http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9794:12
    at forEach (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:341:20)
    at transformData (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9793:3)
    at transformResponse (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10582:21)
    at processQueue (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15097:28)
    at http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15113:27
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16359:28)
```

My code (angular) is given below:

```
  $scope.generate_pdf = function() {
    var html =  angular.element('html').html(); // get all html

    var service = API.getService();
    // JSON.stringify( { html:  html } this also cause same error
    service.downloadPdf({}, { html: html },
      function(res) {
        console.log("res : ", res);
      }, function(err) {
        console.log("err : ", err);
      });


  };
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use `{ html : JSON.stringify(html)}`

Comment: I don't think you can just parse html to json

Comment: Maybe you should encode html code first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: HTML is not JSON.  There doesn't appear to be any reason to try to convert your HTML into JSON; just post the HTML as HTML.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0` means that the server response isn't valid JSON, open the network tab in your console and check the response of the request to see what's wrong.